# Get a list of connected users with PHP

Tags: php, list, sockets, session

In order satisfy a client, I have to create a simple dashboard in PHP, where the customer admin can see a list of connected users.

So, I would like, when a client login on the web site, create a socket. Why ? because if the customer close his browser without logout, so, the socket will be automatically closed. If I use only sessions with a table of connected users and a boolean, if the user closes his browser instead of logout, the table will not be updated ... So for me, it's not a good method.

Does exists a way in order to get the list of opened sockets ? and if yes, it is possible to get the id user associated with the opened socket ?
Or perhaps, there is an other way to proceed ...

PS : I have seen Node.js, that can be very helpful but I can't use this techno. I haven't the permission.

Thx all, I am waiting for any advices or links reference documentation :)

Comment: So you can't run Node. What can you use? Can you use PHP websockets?

Comment: I am using basic php sessions for the moment. When a customer login on the web site, I create a session. What do u mean about PHP websokets ?

Comment: You won't be able to accomplish this without javascript / web sockets.

Comment: U mean this ? http://php.net/manual/fr/book.sockets.php

Comment: Yep, that's square one.

Comment: @QuinnStrahl: it's possible without those, but you're definitely going to need a server that supports long-polling HTTP requests (aka Comet)

Comment: I don't understand, I have to create a server ...
but I have already a server ...
When I have to launch it ? I really don't understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for this. Check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) for PHP, it should do what you need.

Comment: Ok, Thx all for yours answers. I Will see websockets.

Comment: But there is something I don't understand. My web site is already running due to a server OVH. In the example of PHP websocket, I have to create a server with an Ip where I have to listen entries. I don't really undestand how I have to proceed ...

Comment: I think I need an example ... because I don't undertand how I have to implemented this.
My server have to launch another little server where it's listen some entries ? How I join it with my database ? It's very strange for me.

Comment: If you take a look at the Ratchet website you will find plenty of documentation to help you.